# Live monitoring of background jobs

Tags: shell, command-line, background-process, process-management

I executed a command like this: `nohup some_command &`. Now this command is in the background. I can see it with the command `jobs`.

Example output:

```
[1]+  Running                 nohup some_command &
```

Is it somehow possible to have a **live** representation of the status that comes from the `jobs` command, similar to how [`top`](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/top.htm) works? So that when `nohup some_command &` completes, it immediately disappears from the list?

Comment: Have you tried `watch`?

Comment: This is kind of overkill, but you could always start a shell (as root) with `unshare -fp --mount-proc bash`, run a bunch of things in that shell, and then run top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is for job completion notifications to be printed immediately, even if you're at typing a prompt or if some other job is in the foreground, then just run `set -o notify`.

If you want a foreground command that displays the status of background jobs from the current shell, you can run `jobs` in a loop. It's easy to do it in full screen:

```
tput clear
jobs
while sleep 1; do
  tput clear
  jobs
done
```

If you want to display the list below the prompt without clearing the screen, save the cursor position at the beginning and restore it on each run:

```
tput sc
jobs
while sleep 1; do
  tput rc
  jobs
done
```

Comment: This is great and helps me a lot, but I would actually like something more like the top command, except for registered background jobs. Essentially a list of all active jobs that updates when the status changes.

Comment: @Cort3z Do you mean something you'd launch in the same terminal window? Or in another terminal window? I don't understand how you want the list to be displayed and how you'd interact with it.

Comment: Try to write `top` in terminal. I want the exact same thing, only it displays job status, not process status. A foreground program which has a live update of all the background jobs.

Comment: @Cort3z Ok. I've updated my answer, I think this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shell function :

`myjobwatch() { while true; do jobs; sleep 2; clear; done; }`

Then just execute `myjobwatch`

Comment: Wouldn't this clear the entire console?